# Pattern for passing partially loaded, disconnected objects in Entity Framework 4.3 CF on n-tier distributed app?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a EF domain model to pass around information between my ASP.NET MVC controllers and my service layer.    The MVC Controller is disconnected from the data source and relies completely on the service for loading.

I am using EF 4.3 and Code First.

Because of this, I do not use the EF lazy load functionality in the MVC layer of my app.  So, many objects are "partially loaded" as I do not need the data and it's ineffcient to load it.

However, I constantly run into Null Reference Exceptions during development, since there's no way to statically knowing this, short of making a ton of DTOs that represent only the data that is being passed.

I am not fond of creating a lot of DTOs, as that creates a lot more code and mapping issues, and doesn't necessarily reduce the amount of bugs that might be caused.  but I suspect that is the only real way to make my code cleaner here.

Is there a design pattern to account for disconnected, n-tier Entity Framework applications other than DTOs?

Comment: What version of EF, and are you using an EDMX (with model generated entities) or Code First / POCO entities?

Comment: Code First with EF 4.3.  Updated question to reflect that.

Comment: So you're trying to access a a property like: `Invoice.Customer` but the customer record has not been loaded, and you get a NRE right?  Unless you put something there, I'm not sure how you could get around that.